# Passing multiple BlobKey/outputs (from chained MapReduce jobs) to a third MapReduce job in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, pipeline

So far, I have three MapReduce jobs chained together in Google App Engine. Between each MapReduce job, I yield the ouputs and pass that output on to the next MapReduce job.  Now, I would like to pass on two different outputs (each from different MapReduce jobs) to a single MapReduce job. Can anyone suggest as to how to do this?  I will paste in my Pipeline below:

```
num_shards=2
# First define the parent pipeline job
class RecommenderPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
"""A pipeline to run Recommender demo.

Args:
blobkey: blobkey to process as string. Should be a zip archive with
  text files inside.
"""

def run(self, filekey, blobkey, itr):
  logging.debug("------------------PIPELINE FILEKEY is %s" % filekey)
  logging.debug("------------------PIPELINE BLOBKEY is %s" % blobkey)
  output1 = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
    "recommender",
    "main.recommender_group_by_user_rating_map1",
    "main.recommender_count_ratings_user_freq_reduce1",
    "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
    "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
    mapper_params={
        "blob_keys": blobkey,
    },
    reducer_params={
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
    },
    shards=num_shards)
  output1yield = yield BlobKeys(output1)

  # Code below takes output1 and feeds into second mapreduce job.
  # Pipeline library ensures that the second pipeline depends on first and
  # does not launch until the first has resolved.
  output2 = (
  yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
    "recommender",
    "main.recommender_pairwise_items_map2",
    "main.recommender_calc_similarity_reduce2",
    "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
    "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
    mapper_params=(output1yield), #see BlobKeys Class!`
    reducer_params={
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
    },
    shards=num_shards))
  output2yield = yield BlobKeys(output2)

  # Code below takes output2 and feeds into third mapreduce job.
  # Pipeline library ensures that the third pipeline depends on second and
  # does not launch until the second has resolved.
  output3 = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
    "recommender",
    "main.recommender_weighted_sum_map3",
    "main.recommender_weighted_sum_reduce3",
    "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
    "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
    mapper_params=(output2yield), #see BlobKeys Class!`
    reducer_params={
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
    },
    shards=num_shards)
  yield StoreOutput("Recommender", filekey, output3, itr)  #stores key to results
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to change BlobKeys to accept 1 or 2 future results (or you
can use common.Dict with a different key for each pipeline result).

Comment: Thanks again ozarov!  The BlobKeys input is a great idea. Would you be able to elaborate on the common.dict?  I am not sure I follow you. Do you mean using a dictionary to "collect" the BlobKeys output into one object?

Comment: Ozarov, might you be able to explain how to change BlobKeys to accept 2 future results?  I have tried the following but it is not yet working:

Comment: class BlobKeys2(base_handler.PipelineBase):
     """Returns a dictionary with the supplied keyword arguments."""
      def run(self, key1, key2):
        logging.debug("-------------------BLOBKEYS ARE %s" % keys)
        # Remove each key from a string in this format:
        # /blobstore/<key>
        return {
            ["blob_keys": [k.split("/")[-1] for k in key1],
            "blob_keys": [k.split("/")[-1] for k in key2]]
        }

Comment: common.Dict -> https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/source/browse/trunk/src/pipeline/common.py#47 you can use it to assign to mapper_params. combined_output = yield common.Dict(output1=output1yield, output2=output2yield)

Comment: As for BlobKeys. try something like that: values = [k.split("/")[-1] for k in key1]; values.extend([k.split("/")[-1] for k in key2]); return {"blob_keys" : values}